# Deleting controls programmatically

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

I want to remove a UITextField/UIButton/UILabel added to a view on the click of button. How can this be achieved in iOS?

Comment: you want to remove or you want to hide?

Comment: Completely remove it...with its properties...tag,etc.

Comment: removeFromSuperview will work for you. Isn't it working?

Comment: @Purva..Refer raghu_dev answer that solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

To remove you can simply use:

```
[myTextField removeFromSuperview];
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one...

> Blockquote

UILabel *t1;

```
NSArray *arr1=[YourView subviews];
for (UIView *v in arr1)
{
    if([v isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
    {
        t1 = (UILabel *)v;
        if (t1.tag==your_tag)
            [t1 removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

> Blockquote

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[myTextField removeFromSuperview];` to get rid of a view.

Answer (score 0):

```
[myTextField removeFromSuperview]
```

See [UIView documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html).

Answer (score 0):

All controls inherited from UIView.
So you can remove all the controls which added on UIView using like this. By clicking the button action write like this

```
for(UIView *control in [self.view subviews])
{
[control removeFromSuperview];
}
```